# C++, член-тип шаблона

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, using

Рассмотрим следующий код:

```
template <typename T>
class Object
{
public:
    using p1 = unique_ptr<Object>;
    using p2 = unique_ptr<Object<T>>;
    // ...
};
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли разница между `p1` и `p2`?

Comment: Советую почитать про [injected-class-name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name).

Answer (score 7):

Да никакого. Это просто разная запись одного и того же.

Можете [убедиться](https://ideone.com/l3iTb2):

```
void out()
{
    cout << typeid(p1).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid(p2).name() << endl;
}
```

дает один и тот же тип.

Ну, или используйте `is_same`.

Comment: `is_same` всё же правильнее был бы. Т.к. `type_info.name` совсем не гарантирует, что одинаковые результаты говорят об идентичности типов.

Answer (score 1):

Шаблон класса  позволяет задать тип для объектов, используемых в классе, это не влияет на имя класса. Поэтому для   шаблоннного класса:

```
template <class T>
class Object {
    T a;
public: 
    Object<T>(const T k) : a(k) {}
    Object(const T k) : a(k) {}
};
```

Имя `Object` и `Object<T>` идентичны в пределах этой же специализации, и тут присутствует двойное определение одного и того же конструктора

Comment: Конструкторы действительно одинаковые, но я не могу понять, о чем речь в первом абзаце. При чем здесь "вывод типов аргументов шаблона класса"?